# Load audio bytes as a source to <audio>

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html5-audio, wav

After reading a thousand website I still am not able to find the straightforward way to load a WAV file into an audio tag in HTML.

I have the following in my html:

```
<h2>Answer</h2>
<audio controls autoplay id="audioholder">
  <source id="audiosrcholder" src=none type="audio/wav">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

and the following in my script's success function of an AJAX request:

```
success: function(stream) {
            audiosrcholder.src = stream
            {#audiosrcholder.setData(stream)#}
            
            audioholder.load()
        }
```

where I note that the response of the used request contains a WAV audio file with a Content-Type header set to 'audio/wav'.

The idea is to not save the file locally, but directly stream it to the audio control.

If I log the WAV file (stream), I can see the actual WAV content starting with RIFF...
Here is a snippet:
[RIFF����WAVEfmt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuuGr.png)

Comment: The `src` property should be a url, you could use a blob url since you want to use ajax to get the data.

Comment: Indeed I tried this last thing yesterday, but still with vain. In fact, when creating the blob url out of the wave file, it generates an error.

Comment: _"when creating the blob url out of the wave file, it generates an error."_ what is the error? Creating a blob url is the way to play file bytes (like what you've got as Stream)...